# Regex to get area and district codes from UK postcodes

Tags: mysql, regex

Basically, I need a regex that would match first sequence of letters in UK postcode (easy) and another regex which would match the following number (not so easy).

Examples of possible combinations and matches:

```
AA9A 9AA    regex1: AA    regex2: 9
A9A 9AA     regex1: A     regex2: 9
A9 9AA      regex1: A     regex2: 9
A99 9AA     regex1: A     regex2: 99
AA9 9AA     regex1: AA    regex2: 9
AA99 9AA    regex1: AA    regex2: 99
```

Spaces in poscodes are only there for clarity, they might or might not be there, therefor must be disregarded.

I could use some help with these two regular expressions, especially regex2 (matching the number). By the way, I'm gonna be running this in MySQL 5.6

**UPDATE:** Just to note: last 3 characters will always be ignored no matter what, that's the only pattern that always applies - it should be visible from my examples.

**UPDATE2:** Sorry if I wasn't clear enough before - I don't need to validate the post codes, I need to extract area and district codes.

**UPDATE3:** Just to emphasize again: white space must be disregarded, it could be `AA99 9AA` or `AA999AA` - in both cases the regex2 (extract number) should be `99`

**UPDATE4:** Thanks for all your answers, unfortunately I just found out that MySQL can't extract regex matches. Way to go, MySQL, proving to be useless yet again.

Comment: Are area code always 3 characters?

Comment: No. Codes in London are often 4 characters (e.g. SW19 = Wimbledon). So the entire postcode may be 5 to 7 characters long, to my knowledge.

Comment: is there always a space between the first set of alphanumerics and the second set? if not, you should have an example of that - also, can we simply ignore the last three digits? - oh you said that... my bad

Comment: RE: `UPDATE4` what system/language do you have making the MySQL requests? perhaps you can have MySQL filter out results that include these postal codes (unless of course every single record has one) then use PHP, C#, JavaScript, etc. to actually get your data extracted (?)

Comment: @CodeJockey This is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. If I let the code handle it, it will have to loop and do a lot of queries instead of just one query handling it. It would be a breeze in Postgres.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
([A-Z]+)([0-9]+).*?[A-Z0-9]{3}
```

and use matched group `#1` and `#2`

Comment: Wouldn't this match the full number all the time where sometimes it needs to be just a part of it?

Comment: No it won't match full Zip code. Group #1 will be all alphabets from start and group #2 will be all digits followed by those alphabets.

Comment: Useless regex, unless validating. Moreover it do not checks for blank characters.

Comment: @Antoniossss There was no request for checking for blank characters. There was no request for validation. this regex does exactly what was requested. How is it useless?

Comment: @anubhava Only problem is (I have mentioned it) - white space must be disregarded. It could be `AA99 9AA` or `AA999AA`. Wouldn't it fail to extract the right number in this case (99)?

Comment: @CodeJockey did you check that regex for 6 templates of zipcode in UK? If you would, than you would know why it is useless. Try it yourself here :http://regexpal.com/

Comment: @Caballero: I have made one edit after your latest edit and I believe it should work for your cases now.

Answer (score 2):

this regex:

```
([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)([A-Z ]*[0-9][A-Z]{2})
```

works as follows according to RegexBuddy 4 simulation of MySQL's POSIX ERE regex implementation:

```
Input     G1   G2   G3
--------  ---  ---  ------
AA9A 9AA  AA   9    A 9AA
A9A 9AA   A    9    A 9AA
A9 9AA    A    9     9AA
A99 9AA   A    99    9AA
AA9 9AA   AA   9     9AA
AA99 9AA  AA   99    9AA
AA9A9AA   AA   9    A9AA
A9A9AA    A    9    A9AA
A99AA     A    9    9AA
A999AA    A    99   9AA
AA99AA    AA   9    9AA
AA999AA   AA   99   9AA
```

explanation:

```
([A-Z]+)    # captures one or more letters
([0-9]+)    # captures one or more digits
(           # starts 3rd capture group
 [A-Z ]*    # captures zero or more letters or space
 [0-9]      # captures exactly one digit
 [A-Z]{2}   # captures exactly two letters
)           # ends 3rd capture group
```

let me know if I missed a test case that doesn't work, and I'll see what I can do

Answer (score 1):

`"[A-Z](?:\\D\\d\\D|\\d\\D|\\d|\\d{2}|\\D\\d|\\D\\d\\d|EI)\\s??\\d{1}\\D{2}"`
works quite well for me. 
It is littlebit complicated because I use it to fetch zipcode from ONE LINE ADDRESS (whole address with city, country, street names etc, and **not** for validating zipcodes). 
I use it in my production environment.

Comment: Thanks. Which regex is this? To match the area (first letters) or district (following number)?

Comment: I use this regex to mach all possibilities you have provided above (wikipedia?? :)) and I have wrote it and tested myself so can be not 100% accurate, but works in 99,9% cases for me. It capturing blank char so you can always split to your needs

Comment: If I understand this correctly you use this regex for validation? I don't need validation, I need to extract area and district codes like shown in my examples.

Comment: NO, I wrote that i do exactly the opposite - not validation, only exctraction from whole address. Test it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you're looking for:

```
([A-Z]{1,2})(\d+)[A-Z]?\s?\d+[A-Z]{1,2}
```

I've used capture groups for the first and second parts you're after.  I'm assuming you want the number that is in the first part of the post code.